# How to install sshd on the docker file which starts from python

Tags: docker, sshd

I have python image file

```
FROM python:3.9.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

I can make it work on local and can login

```
docker exec -it {container_id} bash
```

Now, I am running it on aws fargate

I need to login the ssd of this container, from ec2.

How can I start sshd?

in container on local

`ps aux | grep sshd`

May be there is no sshd is installed? -> So do I need to install sshd by myself?

Where ths sshd key should be stored?? -> there is no directory under `/home`.

Comment: If you run your Python script without Docker, how do you ssh into the process?  Running an ssh daemon in a container is complicated in multiple ways and almost never necessary, since the container is really just a wrapper around its single main process.  (Running multiple programs in one container, setting up a user with a login, and securely managing credentials are all significant challenges.)

Comment: I see... but I am using fargate  on aws, so I would like to use command line directly. in local docker I can use docker exec -it {container_id} . but in `fargate`, I have no way to log in.

Comment: I quit to install sshd. I will use ECS exec to enter the container on fargate.thank you for your comment